# JavaScript (AirTable Scripting) and trying to extract a the last object in a nested array?

Tags: javascript, airtable

I am VERY new to JavaScript (learning as fast as I can, I am MUCH more familiar with R) and am hoping to use an API ([LegiScan](https://legiscan.com/legiscan)) call to then update an AirTable. I can do some of this...but am running into an issue with trying to get information on "votes". I want to automate, for each bill I call, to pull the most recent (so: last) vote, which is the last object in the "votes" array.

This is my code so far--I have removed my personal API key for privacy.

```
// Setting up API //
let apiToken = '(my API token goes here)'

// Declaring table to be getting bill data from--to be called/updated
let table = base.getTable('Test Bills')

// {} means object restructuring--want records obj w/in that result
let { records } = await table.selectRecordsAsync() 

// Shows it in console, checking to see if it works
 console.log(records)

// >>>Setting up the call as a "for" loop<<<
// Getting a bunch of bill information
for (let record of records) {
    // utilizing getBill call:
    let billUpdate = await remoteFetchAsync(`https://api.legiscan.com/?key=${apiToken}&op=getBill&id=${record.name}`)

// Has to be in json format for AirTable    
    let data = await billUpdate.json()

// To see data (looking at first object in the array to make it easier to see, making sure I know what's going on)
    console.log(data.bill)

// Figuring out the most recent vote--this is not working
    const lastVote = data(data.votes.length - 1)
```

After a few days on this, I think I'm stuck on both:

1. How to set a lastVote variable (I was trying with calling length - 1 to get the last indexed object, but I am now 100% I am doing this incorrectly and cannot figure out how to do it right).
2. If trying with length is even the best idea here--is there an easier way to just call the last object in an array?

Any guidance is appreciated!

Problem:
I tried to use a call (within a loop) for the length - 1 of an array to call the last item in an array (again, throughout the loop). I have experimented with four different ways of trying to call/index, and I am struggling to get something that does not throw an error.

I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at main on line 24
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `data.votes[data.votes.length - 1]`. Or even [`data.votes.at(-1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at).

Comment: it seems that `votes` doesn't exist directly in `data`. how does `data` look like? maybe `data.bill`?